# Morse cohomol. $\cong$ De Rham cohomol.

Tags: homology-cohomology, morse-theory

Are you aware of any short proofs for that fact (references)?
And also for the fact that Morse cohomol. isomorphic to Singular cohomol.

Also, a silly question:

In the following thesis, he proves Morse cohomol$\cong$  sing. coho and then Morse cohomol$\cong$  De Rham coho (pg. 91). 
Doesn't it follow from De Rham's theorem that it is isomorphic to De Rham?

I am guessing he wanted to construct an explicit isomorphism.
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/schaetz_dipl.pdf

Thank you

Comment: http://www.math.umass.edu/~sullivan/797SG/hutchings-morse.pdf here is another proof

Comment: de Rham *co*homology you mean, yes?

Comment: yes,thanks. changed it

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905152v1.pdf by Schwartz